# Magento 1: Why Does the Price Indexer Use the Manage Stock Configuration Flag

Tags: price, magento-1, reindex, manage-stock

In Magento 1's price indexer, the following method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Price.php
public function matchEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)
{
    $data       = $event->getNewData();
    if (isset($data[self::EVENT_MATCH_RESULT_KEY])) {
        return $data[self::EVENT_MATCH_RESULT_KEY];
    }

    if ($event->getEntity() == Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data::ENTITY) {
        $data = $event->getDataObject();
        if ($data && in_array($data->getPath(), $this->_relatedConfigSettings)) {
            $result = $data->isValueChanged();
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    } elseif ($event->getEntity() == Mage_Customer_Model_Group::ENTITY) {
        $result = $event->getDataObject() && $event->getDataObject()->isObjectNew();
    } else {
        $result = parent::matchEvent($event);
    }

    $event->addNewData(self::EVENT_MATCH_RESULT_KEY, $result);

    return $result;
}
```

makes use of the `_relatedConfigSettings` property.  This property contains the XML path to the `cataloginventory/item_options/manage_stock` System Configuration path via the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::XML_PATH_MANAGE_STOCK` constant.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Price.php
protected $_relatedConfigSettings = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_PRICE_SCOPE,
    Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::XML_PATH_MANAGE_STOCK
);
```

Does anyone here understand the reindexing process well enough to understand 1. What this `matchEvent` is used for and 2. Why does it need to reference the global manage stock configuration flag.

I can come up with several theories myself -- but I'm looking for concrete answers to save myself a few days of digging through the code.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but AFAIK it uses stock reference to calculate the minimal price information for configurable/bundle/grouped products. Just to avoid to include out-of-stock products.